# Box2d sensors - contact callback in each step

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I've created a `ContactListener` and a sensor fixture in box2d and would like to get a contact callback in each step. My problem is that `beginContact` and `endContact` are obviously only called when a contact begins and ends but not as long as the contact persists. In these cases it is recommended to use `preSolve` or `postSolve` but these are not implemented for sensors.

How could I get a callback for contacts with a sensor in every step? Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach is now to not using sensors but regular fixtures in this particular case and to call `contact.setEnabled(false)` in `ContactListener.preSolve` to avoid any physical reaction and simulate a sensor.